# Reloading Data into webpage with intvall and page_refresh

Tags: javascript

I made a small script that is given me out some data from textfiles. To refresh the Data i tried to use intvall and just reloading the page.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        setInterval(page_refresh, 5*20000);
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>

    <div id="one">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="bg_desc"><div class="inner_desc"> Top Unterstützer (Monat)</div> </div>
        <div class="inner_background">
        <div id="text">


        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "data1.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
        </script>

    </div>
    </div>

<div id="two">

</div>


<div id="three">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {

loopbox();

function loopbox() {
    $('#one').delay(5).fadeIn(350).delay(40000).fadeOut(350, function() {
      $('#two').fadeIn(200).delay(20000).fadeOut(100, function() {
        $('#three').fadeIn(200).delay(350000).fadeOut(100,function() {                                
        loopbox();
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

This result in the Message "ReferenceError: page_refresh is not defined"
and i can't figure out whats wrong with it.  The second question would be if there is a more elegant solution to reload the data directly if every div comes active without reloading the whole page.

Comment: You haven't defined what is page_refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval(function, interval)` so `page_refresh` should be function

```
function page_refresh(){
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that was indeed missing =)